# How to find track/Keirin races when travelling?

Tags: travelling, track-racing

I'm going to be in Japan for a few weeks in January and was wondering if there are any Keirin races I might be able to attend.  Do they run year round? How would I go about finding a schedule?

Comment: Anybody got more advice than "look for a local velodrome"?  Pretty sure they do run year round, since part of the original purpose of track racing was being able have races regardless of weather.

Comment: One clarification: are you looking for races to watch, or races to participate in?

Answer (score 3):

List of **upcoming keirin races:** 
http://keirin.jp/pc/raceschedule

List of **velodromes in Japan:** 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Velodromes_in_Japan and http://keirin.jp/pc/jyolist

If you need help translating the page, Google Chrome's auto-translation is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently in Japan recently and I remember there were races at the velodrome in Nara.

Here is a list of velodromes in Japan which can translate to English. At the top there are a list of velodromes that have races today and tomorrow. It seems the official schedule can’t be translated on google chrome on the phone but might be able to on a laptop.

Here is a like to the Nara Keirin website. Looks like there are some events on today and tomorrow

https://www.narakeirin.jp/

http://keirin.jp/pc/jyolist